# Python type checking not recognizing type information in docstrings

Tags: python, aiohttp, openapi-generator, typechecking, docstring

I am using an internal library called client_aiohttp, which was generated using [openapi-generator/python-aiohttp](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/python-aiohttp/).

For example here is the add_hosts method in the Clusters class:

```py
# client_aiohttp/api/clusters.py
class Clusters:
  def add_hosts(self, cluster_name, **kwargs):  # noqa: E501
      """add_hosts  # noqa: E501

      A human readable description

      :param cluster_name: (required)
      :type cluster_name: str
      :param body:
      :type body: ApiHostRefList
      :param async_req: Whether to execute the request asynchronously.
      :type async_req: bool, optional
      :return: Returns the result object.
      :rtype: ApiHostRefList
      """
      return self.add_hosts_with_http_info(cluster_name, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
```

However, the vscode python language server (pylance) and mypy do not seem to recognize the type information specified in the docstring.

I have tried searching for a tool or option that can generate a .pyi stub file from the docstrings or enable the evaluation of docstrings, but I haven't found any.

How can I make the type checker recognize the type information specified in the docstrings for proper type checking?

Answer (score 0):

So there is a package called [doc484](https://pypi.org/project/doc484/), which can generate type hints like this:

```py
def read_status(self, cluster_name, service_name, **kwargs):  # noqa: E501
  # type: (str, str, **Any) -> ApiStatusList
```

However returns types are almost never imported in the file so I wrote a bash script to import everything at the start of the line.

```bash
line_to_insert="from client_aiohttp import *"
for file in *.py; do
    temp_file=$(mktemp)
    awk -v new_line="$line_to_insert" 'NR==1 {print} NR==2 {print new_line} NR>2 {print}' "$file" > "$temp_file"
    mv "$temp_file" "$file"
done
```

But when using openapi generator python-aiohttp it only partially solved the problem, because the return type can be either sync or async based on the async_req parameter and calling await on the result removes type information.

```
synchronous HTTP request by default. To make an asynchronous HTTP request, please pass async_req=True

>>> thread = api.read_host(host_id, async_req=True]
>>> result = thread.get()
```

At least some parameters are typed now.